# How do I specify a minimum package version in pipit setup.cfg

Tags: pip, pypi, twine

I am trying to specify a minimum package version in a pypi setup.cfg file.  I have written this:

```
install_requires =
   cocotb>=1.5.2
```

But I get this error message when I test my package installation:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cocotb>=1.5.2 (from pyuvm) (from versions: 1.0.20170128)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cocotb>=1.5.2
```

It seems to be using the version number as part of the package name. When I install **cocotb** manually I see the correct version:

```
(clean) (base) raysalemi@RayProMac pyuvm % pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
cocotb     1.5.2
```

All the help I've seen on this refers to the `setup.py` file, but I am working with the `setup.cfg` file.  What is the syntax to specify a module and version?

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is correct. The problem was that cocotb 1.5.2 is not on `test.pypi.org`

Comment: You must provide the information what `pip` command have you used. Without knowing you used TestPyPI nobody could answer the question.